# index.php file content incorrect, cannot host website

Tags: php, laravel, hosting

I wonder why my index.php content file is incorrect, specifically in registering the autoloader. Mine reads

```
|------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
--
| Register The Auto Loader
|------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
--
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader 
for
| our application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it
| into the script here so that we don't have to worry about manual
| loading any of our classes later on. It feels great to relax.
|
*/

require __DIR__.'/../projectlaravel2/vendor/autoload.php';
```

While other people (in Youtube tutorials that teach how to host websites) have

```
require __DIR__.'/../projectlaravel2/bootstrap/autoload.php';
```

Whenever I try to access my domain, I always get the error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 
'/home/aldohasi/projectlaravel3/vendor/composer/../symfony/polyfill- 
mbstring/bootstrap.php'(include_path='.:/opt/alt/php56/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php56/usr/share/php') in /home/aldohasi/projectlaravel3/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66
```

I did find the autoloader file in my vendor folder, and tried moving it to bootstrap folder, changed vendor in my index.php to bootstrap. I still get the same error. Any thoughts?

Comment: Dont move the vendor files or autoloader, you will break it. Your require does look odd as if your placing or editing files in vendor folder. You shouldn't need to touch anything in vendor. Just goto your folder which has composer.json in and do `composer install` if it borks out it should tell you whats wrong.

Comment: The error says `projectlaravel3` but your index file has `projectlaravel2`...?

Comment: Older versions of Laravel held the autoload in the bootstrap folder. I suggest installing Laravel from composer.

Comment: @Ahsan I had multiple projects and the same problem persisted on all of them. The error message here is the same for projectlaravel2

Comment: Ok, this looks more like setup problem rather than index.php configuration. Which Laravel version are you using?

Comment: @Ahsan I'm using 5.5.37

Comment: For Laravel 5.5 minimun PHP >= 7.0.0. it looks like you are using PHP 5.6

Comment: yeah I found the solution; in the cpanel I need to change the version of PHP there to match that of my computer's, and also to allow zip files to be recognized.